# Listbox.Items.Clear not clearing the items collection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Listbox that is passed through a wrapper class and the wrapper class appears to hold onto the items collection. I have to call lstBox.Items.Clear twice before it will actually clear the items. The items are added using the items.add method so are not bound using a datasource.

Here's the basic code structure:

I have a class called WrapListBox that inherits System.Windows.Forms.Listbox. The WrapListBox overrides the OnDrawItem, OnMeasureItem, OnResize methods hence the wrapper.

My object creates a new instance of WrapListBox in it's initialization method and is passed the WrapListBox (a Listbox on the form) via a standard property.

So the code snippet would look like this:

```
m_WorkItem = New WorkItem
m_WorkItem.PreviewMessages = lvwMessages
```

lvwMessages is the ListBox on the form.
m_WorkItem.PreviewMessages passes the ListBox to a member variable, m_log.

```
Public Property PreviewMessages() As WrapListBox
    Get
        Return m_log
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As WrapListBox)
        m_log = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then I have another wrapper class, WrapListBoxLogger that is passed the m_log object and handles the adding of items to the list box. m_log is passed into the New constructor of the WrapListBoxLogger and it passes the m_log object to another member variable mlstDestination which is of type WrapListBox.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal lstDestination As WrapListBox)
    mlstDestination = lstDestination
End Sub
```

If I call m_log.items.clear the items collection does not change. If I call m_log.items.clear again then the items are cleared. I've tried creating events and handling them back on the form that contains the original list box, I've tried calling the clear method at various point across the chain but still nothing is cleared until the second clear call.

I can only imagine there's some lingering reference to the object that is preventing it from being cleared but I can't work out what it is. I'm hoping someone can help me identify the solution?

If you have gotten down to this line, thanks for taking the time to read. If you have any questions about the code structure please do ask.

Edit:
    Public Class WrapListBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

```
Private Shared ReadOnly STRING_FORMAT As StringFormat = CreateStringFormat()

Private Shared Function CreateStringFormat() As StringFormat
    Dim sf As New StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
    sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisWord
    Return sf
End Function

Protected Const MARGIN_OUTER As Integer = 2
Protected Const MARGIN_INNER As Integer = 4
Protected Const ICON_WIDTH As Integer = 20

Private mobjImageList As ImageList

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Me.DrawMode = Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
    Me.IntegralHeight = False
    Me.UseTabStops = True
    Me.ResizeRedraw = True
End Sub

Public Property ImageList() As ImageList
    Get
        Return mobjImageList
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ImageList)
        mobjImageList = Value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs)
    If Me.DesignMode Then Exit Sub

    'Debug.WriteLine("OnDrawItem " & e.Index & " : " & e.Bounds.ToString)

    If e.Index > -1 AndAlso e.Index < Me.Items.Count Then
        Dim objItem As WrapListBoxItem = DirectCast(Me.Items(e.Index), WrapListBoxItem)
        Dim objBrush As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        Dim objPen As New Pen(e.ForeColor)
        Dim objGraphics As Graphics = e.Graphics
        objGraphics.Clip = New Region(e.Bounds)

        ' draw background
        objBrush.Color = Me.BackColor
        objGraphics.FillRectangle(objBrush, e.Bounds)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()

        ' draw border
        Dim rectBorder As Rectangle = e.Bounds
        rectBorder.X += MARGIN_OUTER
        rectBorder.Y += MARGIN_OUTER
        rectBorder.Height -= MARGIN_OUTER * 2
        rectBorder.Width -= MARGIN_OUTER * 2
        If CBool(e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) Then
            objPen.Color = SystemColors.Highlight
            objPen.Width = 2
        Else
            objPen.Color = SystemColors.Control
            objPen.Width = 1
        End If
        objGraphics.DrawRectangle(objPen, rectBorder)

        ' size caption area
        Dim rectCaption As New RectangleF(rectBorder.X, rectBorder.Y, rectBorder.Width, rectBorder.Height)
        rectCaption.X += MARGIN_INNER
        rectCaption.Y += MARGIN_INNER
        rectCaption.Height -= MARGIN_INNER * 2
        rectCaption.Width -= MARGIN_INNER * 2

        ' draw icon
        If Not mobjImageList Is Nothing AndAlso objItem.ImageIndex > -1 Then
            Dim objImage As Image = mobjImageList.Images(objItem.ImageIndex)
            objGraphics.DrawImage(objImage, rectCaption.X, rectCaption.Y)
            rectCaption.X += ICON_WIDTH
            rectCaption.Width -= ICON_WIDTH
        End If

        ' draw caption
        objBrush.Color = Me.ForeColor
        objGraphics.DrawString(objItem.Text, e.Font, objBrush, rectCaption, STRING_FORMAT)

        objBrush.Dispose()
        objPen.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMeasureItem(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs)
    If Me.DesignMode Then Exit Sub
    If e.Index > -1 AndAlso e.Index < Me.Items.Count Then
        Dim objItem As WrapListBoxItem = DirectCast(Me.Items(e.Index), WrapListBoxItem)
        Dim sngWidth As Single = Me.Width - ((MARGIN_OUTER * 2) + (MARGIN_INNER * 2))
        If Not mobjImageList Is Nothing AndAlso objItem.ImageIndex > -1 Then
            sngWidth -= ICON_WIDTH
        End If
        Dim areaSize As SizeF = New SizeF(sngWidth, 100)

        'Limit the length of the text to measure otherwise you get a generic GDI+ error
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(objItem.Text) AndAlso objItem.Text.Length > 10000 Then
            objItem.Text = objItem.Text.Substring(0, 10000)
        End If
        Dim textSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(objItem.Text, Me.Font, areaSize)
        e.ItemHeight = CInt(textSize.Height) + (MARGIN_OUTER * 2) + (MARGIN_INNER * 2)
        e.ItemWidth = Me.Width

        'Debug.WriteLine("OnMeasureItem (" & e.ItemWidth.ToString & "," & e.ItemHeight.ToString & ")")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnResize(e)
    Me.BeginUpdate()
    Me.RefreshItems()
    Me.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(WrapListBox))
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'WrapListBox
    '
    resources.ApplyResources(Me, "$this")
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub

Public Class WrapListBoxItem

    Private m_imageIndex As Integer = -1
    Private m_text As String = String.Empty
    Private m_tag As Object = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String)
        m_text = strText
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal intImage As Integer)
        m_text = strText
        m_imageIndex = intImage
    End Sub

    Public Property ImageIndex() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_imageIndex
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_imageIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return m_text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Tag() As Object
        Get
            Return m_tag
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            m_tag = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

End Class

Comment: Can you include the class declaration for WrapListBox, WrapListBoxLogger and the overridden Items properties (if any)?

Comment: OK, so the WrapListBoxLogger is used to add WrapListBoxItem object to the list box. I've moved all code used to add items to the instantiating class so WrapListBoxLogger is no longer used. I wanted to remove that layer of complexity in case that was causing the lingering reference but the problem still remains.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the definition of the WrapListBox if it helps...

Comment: OK, so I've changed the listbox to use a DataSource of a list of objects. I didn't think that was working at first because the listbox still appeared to have duplicated items in it but as it turns out that I also needed to invalidate the listbox so that it would be re-drawn. So that is working. It still doesn't help me understand why I can't just clear the original items collection though. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've changed the WrapListBox for a standard ListBox and that works as expected, i.e. one call to items.clear, so can anyone see why the WrapListBox class (above) would cause this problem?